# I want to be able to save my attachment data into my mysql database. I am guessing that means I have to save my attachment data into a TStream

Tags: delphi, stream, email-attachments, indy

I am trying to insert my attachment data from an IMAP Server to a MySQL database using TBlobStream Methods.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  imap_message_count:Integer;
  current_record:Integer;
  imap_id:String;

  email_parts_count:Integer;
  current_email_part:Integer;


  attachment_stream:TStream;
  blob_stream:TStream;
  final_stream:TStream;

  attachment_data_set:TDataSet;
  attachment_data:TFDQuery;
  blob_field:TField;
begin
  IdIMAP41.Connect();
  if IdIMAP41.SelectMailBox('INBOX') then
  BEGIN
    imap_message_count := IdIMAP41.MailBox.TotalMsgs;
    for current_record := 1 to imap_message_count - 1 do
    begin
      IdIMAP41.GetUID(current_record, imap_id);
      IdIMAP41.UIDRetrieve(imap_id, IdMessage1);
      email_parts_count := IdMessage1.MessageParts.Count;
      for current_email_part := 1 to email_parts_count - 1 do
      begin
        if IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part] is TIdAttachment then
        begin
          attachment_stream := TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).OpenLoadStream;
          try
           AttachmentsTable.Insert;
           blob_field := AttachmentsTable.FieldByName('attachment');
            blob_stream := AttachmentsTable.CreateBlobStream(blob_field, bmWrite);
              try
                blob_stream.CopyFrom(attachment_stream, 0);
              finally
                AttachmentsTable.Post;
                blob_stream.Free;
              end;
           finally
            TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).CloseLoadStream;
           end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  END;

end;
```

Currently I am able to insert an ID as it is autoincremented but when I look at my Data Base attachment field I end up getting a result of Null. What could be my issue?

I am guessing I am not accessing my blob_stream data correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part] is TIdAttachment then
        begin     
              attachment_stream := TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).OpenLoadStream;
          try
           AttachmentsTable.Insert;
           blob_field := AttachmentsTable.FieldByName('attachment');
           blob_stream := AttachmentsTable.CreateBlobStream(blob_field, bmWrite);
              try
                blob_stream.CopyFrom(attachment_stream, attachment_stream.Size);
              finally
                blob_stream.Free;
                AttachmentsTable.Post;
              end;
           finally
            TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).CloseLoadStream;
           end;
        end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, but you are doing things the wrong way.

To access an attachment's existing data, use its `OpenLoadStream()` method, eg:

```
var
  att_stream: TStream;

if IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part] is TIdAttachment then
begin
  att_stream := TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).OpenLoadStream();
  try
    // use att_stream data as needed, 
    // such as saving it to a DB... 
  finally
    TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).CloseLoadStream();
  end;
end;
```

`PrepareTempStream()` is meant for saving new data to the attachment. `OpenLoadStream()` is meant for reading data from the attachment.

Comment: This helped a lot. Would you mind continuing the example to show how I would use the actual contents from OpenLoadStream() and be able to save the file? I plan to use a procedure that stores that content onto my database.

Comment: @FranciscoOchoa the easiest way is to use `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` to get a writable `TStream` for the desired DB field, and then you call its `CopyFrom()` method to copy the attachment `TStream` data into the DB field

Comment: attachment_stream := TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).OpenLoadStream;
              try
                attachment_stream.Size;
                attachment_data_set := ClientDataSet1;
                attachment_stream := attachment_data_set.CreateBlobStream(AttachmentsTable.FieldByName('attachment'), bmReadWrite);
                final_stream.CopyFrom(attachment_stream, attachment_stream.Size);
              finally
                TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).CloseLoadStream;
              end;

Comment: My code now looks like that but when I get to the line that starts with  attachment_stream := attachment_data_set.CraeteBlobField... I get the error Invalid Typecast. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @FranciscoOchoa that code is completely wrong on many levels. It should be more like this instead: `var attachment_stream, blob_stream: TStream; ... attachment_stream := TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).OpenLoadStream; try blob_stream := ClientDataSet1.CreateBlobStream(AttachmentsTable.FieldByName('attachment'), bmWrite); try blob_stream.CopyFrom(attachment_stream, 0); finally blob_stream.Free; end; finally TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[current_email_part]).CloseLoadStream; end;`

Comment: I get the same error and it breaks at the same line.

Comment: And which line would that be *exactly*? `CreateBlobStream()` takes a `TField` and returns a `TStream`. `FieldByName()` returns a `TField`, and `attachment_stream` is a `TStream`? So where is the typecast it is complaining about? What I showed is known to work when used correctly, so you have to be doing something wrong with it. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] of your actual code.